# Filtering MySQL query result according to a interval of timestamp

Tags: mysql, performance

Let's say I have a very **large** MySQL table with a timestamp field. So I want to filter out some of the results not to have too many rows because I am going to print them.

Let's say the timestamps are increasing as the number of rows increase and they are like every one minute **on average**. *(Does not necessarily to be exactly once every minute, ex: 2010-06-07 03:**55**:14, 2010-06-07 03:**56**:23, 2010-06-07 03:**57**:01, 2010-06-07 03:**57**:51, 2010-06-07 03:**59**:21 ...)*

As I mentioned earlier I want to filter out some of the records, I do not have specific rule to do that, but I was thinking to filter out the rows according to the timestamp interval. After I achieve filtering I want to have a result set which has a certain amount of minutes between timestamps **on average** *(ex: 2010-06-07 03:**20**:14, 2010-06-07 03:**29**:23, 2010-06-07 03:**38**:01, 2010-06-07 03:**49**:51, 2010-06-07 03:**59**:21 ...)*

Last but not least, the operation should **not** take incredible amount of time, I need this functionality to be almost fast as a normal select operation.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to come up with a query that would do this off the top of my head, but here's what I was thinking:

1. If you have a lot of entries within a single minute, figure out a way to collapse the results such that there is max 1 entry for any given minute (`DISTINCT`, `DATE_FORMAT` maybe?).
2. Limit the number of results by using modulus on the minute value, something like this (if you'd like an entry from every 10 minutes):

`WHERE MOD(MINUTE(tstamp_column, 10)) = 0`

Comment: I guess those are the only approaches, possible.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to filter records, presumably what you really want is a small percentage of the records, but not the first 10 or 100.  In which case, which not just select them randomly?  The MySQL [RAND()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) function will return a floating point number n, such that 0 <= n < 1.0.  Convert your desired percentage to a floating point number, and use it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE RAND() < 0.001
```

If you want repeatable results (for testing), you can use a seed parameter to force the function to always return the same set of numbers.